# Simple air resistance experiment

Tags: home-experiment, air, drag

I have a paper plate, and I'm taping paper streamers to it. I have 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 streamers. I tried to place the streamers at places equidistant from the next. 2mm are attached to the plate and the remaining 30 mm hang down from the plate. I did 5 trials each and ran through the experiment twice. The first time I had no upward or downward trend of time taken for the plate to fall to the floor. The second I had an upward trend of time taken. I know this experiment is vastly oversimplifying reality, and I need to consider a lot of factors. But for this simple experiment I was wondering if the upward trend is supposed to be the "expected" because I'm increasing the surface area and it increases drag/air resistance?

Comment: An upward trend in what?

Comment: Sorry! time taken for the plate to fall to the floor.

Comment: Two runs is hardly sufficient to notice a trend. Run your experiment 20+ times and see what you get. Then you'll be in a better position to tell which trial is an outlier.

Answer (score -1):

Air drag does not depend alone on the surface area of the object, but its value of mass/surface area..

If you can increase the surface area of the object while keeping it's mass the same, it will influence the air drag on it. But if you increase the surface area while also increasing the mass, it will go unchanged.

Comment: This is incorrect. Drag depends only on surface area. What you're thinking of is [terminal velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity), which depends on both.

Comment: You are right. Indeed I was wrong in my definition that drag depends on mass too. What caused this confusion was that o.p stated that he was measuring the time taken by the plates to fall on the ground, which incorporates velocity of the falling object (which in turn is dependant on mass) instead of the drag that air offers against the falling object.

I think o.p is mixing up velocity of the falling object with air resistance. Or maybe my interpretation is faulty.

Comment: Velocity depends on the net force, so you've interpreted OP's intentions correctly. However, drag still doesn't depend on mass, so you should change that bit in your answer.